# How to save StorageFolder

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro

I am creating a (sort-of) downloading manager for windows 8 as a metro app. I need to let the user pick his download directory.

So we can get a reference to a folder using the folder picker:

```
Windows.storate.Pickers.FolderPicker.pickSingleFolderAsync.then(function (folder)  
{
   //myFolder
   folder
}
```

Now my question is how would I save this `folder` reference, so that I can still access it after the user closes the app?

There seems to be `applicationData` that we can use, but does that keep the folder permission in-tact?

I'm using HTML+JS, though since this is an API question it doesn't really matter.

Answer (score 0):

The recommended way to keep track of the folder is to use the [AccessCache APIs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.accesscache.storageitemaccesslist.aspx), which will keep track of the files and folders your app has been given permissions for from the pickers.
To store a folder in the cache:

```
var folder = //Get a folder from the picker
var storageItemAccessList = Windows.Storage.AccessCache.StorageApplicationPermissions.futureAccessList;
storageItemAccessList.Add(folder,"identifyingString");
```

And to get the same folder out of the cache later use GetFolderAsync with the identifying string that you used when you stored the folder.

Note that the folder will be kept in the cache even if it has been deleted on the disk. You will get a FileNotFound exception when you try and open it though.